# Store function to variable in Php

Tags: php, function, variables

I'd like to store a function in a variable, is that possible?
Let's see this example

```
<?php 

$tot_prezzo = 200;
$x = 75;
$y = 25;

function addition() {
     echo $GLOBALS['imponibile'] = $GLOBALS['tot_prezzo'] + $GLOBALS['x'];
}

$func = 'addition';
$func();


?>
```

How can I store "$func()" in a variable?
I've tried with -> $func_var = $func(), but it doesn't work.
What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to do that since you can just call `addition()` anywhere. What would you be saving?

Comment: are you looking for the value of the sum inside the function?

Comment: I wanted to use the result of the function in a js script, in order to transform the php variable to a js variable. Is it correct to do like this: `var func = <?php addition(); ?>;`?

Answer (score 2):

This is called "Lambda Functions" and can be used like this:

```
$addition = function($a, $b) {
    return $a+$b;
};

echo $addition(1,2); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a value from the function you simply have to `return` it.

```
$tot_prezzo = 200;
$x = 75;
$y = 25;

function addition($tot_prezzo,$x,$y) {

    $imponibile = $tot_prezzo + $x;

    return $imponibile;
}

$result = addition($tot_prezzo,$x,$y);

print $result;
```

Note the use of arguments instead of `$GLOBALS` also you are not using the `$y` variable.